# Standard default first argument to pass to fn.apply

Tags: javascript

I have recently learned about the magic of `fn.apply()` in Javascript, and I am using it to save function calls with all their arguments intact and call them at a later date.

However, in my use case, I do not need the first argument, the context (`this`), and I'd like to avoid passing the `this` object into it somehow in order to make it clear in my code that I'm not using `.apply()` for that.

My first thought was passing in `null`, but I read the following on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply):

> if the method is a function in non-strict mode code, `null` and `undefined` will be replaced with the global object, and primitive values will be boxed.

This seems to imply that passing `null` or even `false` is bad practice. What would be an appropriately falsy, empty, or otherwise obviously placeholder value to put into `fn.apply()`'s first argument?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> This seems to imply that passing `null` or even `false` is bad practice

No, it's not. Admittedly `false` is a bit weird as a `this` value, but the problem that MDN warns about are sloppy-mode functions. Examples:

```
function sloppy() {
    console.log(this);
}
function strict() {
    "use strict";
    console.log(this);
}
sloppy.call(null); // <Window> (or whatever the global object is)
sloppy.call(false); // Boolean {}
strict.call(null); // null
strict.call(false); // false
```

So just use [strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode) and you'll be fine. And don't be surprised that you can't get primitive `this` values in sloppy mode functions.

Using `null` or `undefined` is recommended if you want to pass no value.

Comment: What do you think about passing in `0`?

Comment: Same thing as with `false`.

Comment: @torazaburo: it will become boxed as a `{Number:0}`. @Bergi: To my great shame, I confess that we have not yet refactored our app to use strict mode, though we will soon. What about passing in `{}`?

Comment: @sg.cc: No, you should just pass `null`. I mean, if you're not caring about the value, your function doesn't use the `this` keyword at all, so you don't need to worry? Creating an empty object seems counterproductive.

Comment: Okay, I thought that having JS transform `null` into the `window` object would be more counterproductive than instantiate a `{}`. Thank you for the answer.

Comment: There's no special or problematic "transformation". The same thing happens if you call the function without apply, i.e. `sloppy()` or `strict()` - the first will implicitly get the global object context, the second one `undefined`.